# Can I tell CSS to word-break only on '/' or '\'?

Tags: css, html-table, word-break

I have a long chunk of text which is a file path within a td that causes the whole thing to be 600+pixels wide, when I want to be fit within 200 px.

I can enable word-break:break-all and have it display the whole thing breaking between characters but then it cuts the folder names in half.

So, ideally I'd like to break the lines only upon '/' or '\' characters.  Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can’t; there is no CSS construct for such purposes at present.

What you can do to [suggest allowed line break points](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) is to use a `<wbr>` tag *or* a zero-width space after each “/” or “\”. You could do this dynamically with JavaScript, traversing the relevant text nodes.

Comment: Very nice to know about <wbr>, I'm curious.. sounds like the same thing but how would I insert a zero-width space?

Comment: A zero-width space (U+200B) can be inserted as such when you use a good editor, but it can also be included using the character reference `&#x200b;`. It’s logically more or less the same as `<wbr>` but at different protocol level (character data level vs. markup level) and with some differences in browser support. If you can ignore IE 6, the zero-width space is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with CSS alone. But here is a way to do it using JQuery:

```
function (yourObject) {
    yourObject.html(yourObject.html()
                              .replace(///g, '<br>')
                              .replace(/\/g, '<br>'));
}
```

This is assuming that your object doesn't contain html within it. If it does, it would replace the slashes, so you would need to check for a > following the slash.

Comment: While this would insert line breaks on slashes, I would prefer it to be able to only break on some and not others and I believe this would break on all slashes. Thanks Mayabelle!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to wrap the long text in a container element that allows scrolling, like StackOverflow does with code blocks:

```
.longtext {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    word-break: none;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NCNSa/